# Exposing package through stack exec

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I have been trying build and run an application that needs access to the `ghc` package but I can't manage to expose it through `stack`.

I know this should be an easy flag `-package ghc` but how do I do that with stack?

I've tried this:
`stack exec Engine-exe --package ghc-7.10.3 -- core`

I get this:

```
Didn't see ghc-7.10.3 in your package indices.
Updating and trying again.
Fetching package index ...remote: Counting objects: 1, done.
remote: Total 1 (delta 0), reused 1 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (1/1), done.
Fetched package index.
The following package identifiers were not found in your indices: ghc-7.10.3
Perhaps you meant gc, ghci, ght, or lhc?
```

I've also tried to build it as: `stack build --ghc-options -package ghc`
 and get the same result.

Comment: There isn't a GHC package, neither on Stackage, nor on Hackage. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had forgotten about this!

For future reference.

In the end all I had to do was `ghc-pkg expose ghc`.

Answer (score 2):

If your application needs to build against `ghc`, then add it to the `build-depends` in your cabal file.  If your application needs to run the ghc executable, then it will be visible from within `stack exec`.

So if your project is using ghc-7.10.3, the proper ghc version should be on the PATH.

If you want `stack exec` to use a different resolver or compiler than configured, do `stack --resolver lts-6.0`, or `stack exec --compiler ghc-7.10.3`

Comment: I already have `ghc` and `ghc-paths` in the `build-depends` of the project.

I am using GHC API to compile some modules to Core but somehow it fails to compile hidden modules inside a package I believe, so I was trying to follow advice from [this](http://codeutopia.net/blog/2011/08/20/adventures-in-haskell-dynamic-loading-and-compiling-of-modules/) blogpost to see if I could solve the problems